# Extjs align two xtype elements

Tags: extjs

Hi I am working on displaying a form where i have a checkbox with some configuration input(textField). How can i display them side by side? Below is the code written in ExtJS. I have some hard time coming up with a solution.

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'label1',
    name: 'label1',
    checked: false,
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Config for checkbox',
    name: 'ConfigForCheckBox',
},
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,SS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
{
    xtype       : 'compositefield'
    ,hideLabel  : true
    ,labelWidth : 100
    ,items         : [{ 
        xtype  : 'displayfield'
        ,width : 120
        ,value : 'label1'

    },{
        xtype   : 'checkbox',
        name    :'label1',
        checked : false,
        },{
        xtype  :  'displayfield'
        ,width : 20
    },{
        xtype   : 'textfield'
        ,width  : 120
        ,name   : 'ConfigForCheckBox'
    }]
}
```

refer this : 
[CompositeField](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/CompositeField.html#cls-Ext.form.CompositeField)

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

Create column layout and on second column hide Label for your input.